# If $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and not bounded above implies...

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$Conj:$ If $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and not bounded above implies there exists $\{ x_n\}$ such that $x_n \rightarrow \infty$ and $f(x_n)\rightarrow \infty$.

I can see how to show $f(x_n) \rightarrow \infty$ but not $x_n \rightarrow \infty$:

$Proof:$
For any $M$ there exists $x_1$ such that $f(x_1)>M$ by hypothesis.  Now, choose $N = f(x_1)$. There exists $x_2$ such that $f(x_2)>f(x_1)>M$. Continue iteratively to construct $\{x_n\} = \{x_1, x_2, \dots\}$. Now for all $K>0$ exists $n^*$ such that $n>n^*$ implies $f(x_n)> K$. Thus $f(x_n) \rightarrow \infty$.

Now what? Thanks!

Comment: You mean on $[0,\infty)$, I think.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your argument, you have only shown that$$f(x_1)<f(x_2)<\cdots\ .$$This does not imply that $f(x_n)\to\infty$.

Comment: Right you are, Carlson. Thanks!

Comment: David, can you elaborate why?

Comment: @k-dubs instead of saying choose $N=f(x_1)$ choose $N$ to be $M+1$. Then if you continue the function should go to infinity. It is somewhat of a shabby answer to say this, but there are uncountably many values such $N$ such that $N>M$. So we could technically build a sequence which for one, could converge to some other real number, and for two would never get to infinity via our construction.

Comment: @Eoin, got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instead simplify a little your proof:

For each $n$, the set $[0, x_{n}+1]$ is compact, therefore $f$ is attaining a maximum $N$. Pick $x_{n+1}$ so that $f(x_{n+1})>N+1$.

This implies that 
$$x_{n+1} \geq x_n +1$$
and 
$$f(x_{n+1}) \geq N+1 \geq f(x_n)+1$$

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. One comment: Could it just be $f(x_{n+1}) > N \implies x_{n+1} > x_n+1$?

Comment: @k-dubs Yes it is, I picked $N+1$ to make sure that $f(x_n)$ is also increasing by $1$.

Answer (score 0):

To show that $\{x_n\}$ tends to infinity we can use the following argument about compactness and continuous functions.

Since $[0,x]$ is a compact set $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^+$, and $f$ is a continuous function from this set to $\mathbb{R}$, $f([0,x])$ must be compact and therefore closed and bounded. Then if it is the case that $f(x_n)\rightarrow \infty$, it follows $x_n\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

To finish up, suppose your sequence $(x_n)$ did not go to $\infty$. Equivalently, there exists some $X<\infty$ such that infinitely many $x_n<X$. Say these are $x_{n_k}$. Then you have a sequence $(x_{n_k})$ on the closed and bounded set $[0,X]$, on which the values of the continuous function $f$ are unbounded, and...

Comment: Hmm, I don't see the contradiction. Isn't the sequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ on $[0, X)$ in that case? I can see then by Bolzano-Weierstrass that the subsequence converges but why couldn't $f$ be exploding at that limit point and thus unbounded?

Comment: To see the issue, observe that we could just as well have written $x_n\leq X$.